# SQL Joins with Five tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a SQL Database containing five tables.

**tblExpense** : Expense_ID, Expense_Catagory, Expense_Date, Expense_Particular, Expense_Amount

**tblExpenseTransaction** : Expense_Transaction_ID, Expense_ID, Transaction_ID

**tblStudentMain** : Student_Main_ID, Student_Name

**tblStudentTransaction** : Student_Transaction_ID, Student_Main_ID, Transaction_ID

**tblTransaction** : Transaction_ID, Transaction_Date, Transaction_Amount

Now **tblTransaction** contains transactions done by students or expenses and are connected by between tables( i.e. **tblStudentTransaction** and **tblExpenseTransaction**). The Relations are like **tblStudent -> tblStudentTransactions -> tblTransactions** and **tblExpense -> tblExpenseTransaction -> tblTransaction**.

> Now My Task is to retrieve all the transactions made **only by Students** or **Expenses**.

I tried to do that using this query :

```
SELECT     tblTransaction.Transaction_ID, tblTransaction.Transaction_Date,        tblTransaction.Transaction_Amount, tblTransaction.Transaction_Particular, tblTransaction.Transaction_Mode, 
                  tblTransaction.Is_Deposit
FROM         tblTransaction INNER JOIN
                  tblStudentTransaction ON tblTransaction.Transaction_ID = tblStudentTransaction.Transaction_ID INNER JOIN
                  tblStudentMain ON tblStudentTransaction.Student_Main_ID = tblStudentMain.Student_Main_ID
```

which gives me result. But when i tried to do that with other set of tables with this :

```
SELECT     tblTransaction.Transaction_ID, tblTransaction.Transaction_Date, tblTransaction.Transaction_Amount, tblTransaction.Transaction_Particular, tblTransaction.Transaction_Mode, 
                  tblTransaction.Is_Deposit
FROM         tblTransaction INNER JOIN
                  tblExpenseTransaction ON tblTransaction.Transaction_ID = tblExpenseTransaction.Transaction_ID RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                  tblExpense ON tblExpenseTransaction.Expense_ID = tblExpense.Expense_ID
```

query returned rows with transactions related to student also.

Now i know that, i need to use RIGHT, LEFT or either JOIN but i am confused. Please give me idea if anyone have.

Comment: Just don't do outer join?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need a single query that indicates if the transaction is associated with an expense, a student or neither:

```
SELECT t.*, CASE 
    WHEN e.Transaction_ID IS NOT NULL THEN 'Expense'
    WHEN s.Transaction_ID IS NOT NULL THEN 'Student'
    ELSE 'Other'
END AS Type
FROM tblTransaction t
LEFT JOIN tblExpenseTransaction e ON e.Transaction_ID = t.Transaction_ID
LEFT JOIN tblStudentTransaction s ON s.Transaction_ID = t.Transaction_ID
WHERE Type = 'Expense'
```

Or you could specify ``` Type = 'Student`` to get all student-related transactions, or ```Type = 'Other'` for others, or leave off the WHERE clause off to get all transactions and their type.

Comment: @jarlh UNION ALL could produce duplicate rows if a transaction can be linked to both a student and an expense, because UNION removes duplicates (UNION ALL preserves duplicates). However, it seems an unlikely situation.

Comment: NOPE. I don't want both results at a time. Expense and Students queries should not be mixed up. Now assume there isn't a expense related tables and Transaction table contains records other than student transactions. Now if i need to retrieve transaction related to students only, how should i do it ?

Comment: @MahadevMalkar is that more what you want?

Comment: @Bohemian : I didn't get you properly. And i want results as per above comment. Can you help ?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding individually you are getting the records for the student and expense using the below queries thus try adding union to the two and you should get the requisite data.

As expense and student are individual entities thus I dont think there would be any overlapping / common records between the two tables thus inner join should work fine for you.

```
SELECT     tblTransaction.Transaction_ID, tblTransaction.Transaction_Date, tblTransaction.Transaction_Amount, 
          tblTransaction.Transaction_Particular, tblTransaction.Transaction_Mode, 
                  tblTransaction.Is_Deposit
FROM         tblTransaction INNER JOIN
                  tblStudentTransaction ON tblTransaction.Transaction_ID = tblStudentTransaction.Transaction_ID INNER JOIN
                  tblStudentMain ON tblStudentTransaction.Student_Main_ID = tblStudentMain.Student_Main_ID

union

SELECT     tblTransaction.Transaction_ID, tblTransaction.Transaction_Date, tblTransaction.Transaction_Amount,
          tblTransaction.Transaction_Particular, tblTransaction.Transaction_Mode, 
                  tblTransaction.Is_Deposit
FROM         tblTransaction INNER JOIN
                  tblExpenseTransaction ON tblTransaction.Transaction_ID = tblExpenseTransaction.Transaction_ID  INNER JOIN
                  tblExpense ON tblExpenseTransaction.Expense_ID = tblExpense.Expense_ID
```

Comment: NOPE. I don't want both results at a time. Expense and Students queries should not be mixed up. Now assume there isn't a expense related tables and Transaction table contains records other than student transactions. Now if i need to retrieve transaction related to students only, how should i do it ?